# Copyright: Can we copy an image from an article and paste it into our questions / answers emphasising it belongs to the paper?

Tags: discussion, images, papers

It may be a silly question but I was about to use an image from an article in order to support my post (citing the article / authors), but I don't know if is there some kind of copyright infringement by doing that.

I would guess it may depend on the article but I just wanted to know if there is a general advise to follow on this.

Comment: It looks like a similar question has been asked before on meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240736/what-should-moderators-or-passing-editors-do-about-suspected-plagiarized-or-co Does this answer your question?

Comment: Wow, whuber is fast!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the links, and apologies for not finding them before (I thought I had searched enough for them but clealy I didn't)

Comment: No harm done; no need to apologize. Asking a duplicate actually helps the website because it improves the page rank of the linked questions and helps people who phrased the question using the language in your post (as opposed to the other posts).